# not able to write make file

Tags: assembly, makefile, x86, nasm

I have made a small program in assembly language which is executing fine. I also have the commands to execute it but I don't know how to make a makefile to automate the same.
The command I used is:

```
nasm -f bin boot2.asm -o boot2.bin && qemu-system-x86_64 -fda boot2.bin
```

How do I make a makefile for the same?

Answer (score 3):

Simple version:

```
all: build run

build: boot2.bin

boot2.bin: boot2.asm
    nasm -f bin boot2.asm -o boot2.bin

run: boot2.bin
    qemu-system-x86_64 -fda boot2.bin

clean:
    -rm boot2.bin
```

Comment: There is a follow-up question about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65378980/makefile-not-compiling

Comment: If I had to guess what they did in the followup - the Makefile they put in their question isn't the same one they are using. The one that doesn't work has placed `build run` on the line after `all:` when it should be all one line like `all: build run` . That would explain why it is trying to run build as a command and why the error would be appearing on line 2.